Helping for the code of Inventory routing problem in the CPLEX OPL
I'm final year student doing my project which I need to create a multi product multi period Inventory Routing Problem model in CPLEX and I got stuck on the "Constraint 5" which it annouced as:
CPLEX(default) cannot extract expression: forall(<p,i,t,d> in DemandSet) r[p][i][(t+(-1))]+r[p][i][t]*(-1)+sum(v in 1..10) (sum(j in CustomerSupplierSet) y[p][v][<j,i>][t]+sum(k in CustomerSupplierSet) y[p][v][<i,k>][t]) == d.
Index out of bound for array "r": 1.
I would be so grateful if someone could help me to fix the problem, thank you so much.
Here is the data file
Here is the model:
.mod
int V = 10;// number of vehicles
int f = 610000;// fixed cost
int T = 12;// time periods
int Cus = 18;//number of customers
int P = 10;// number of products

range Node = 0 .. Cus;
range Customer = 1 .. Cus;
range Vehicle = 1 .. V;
range Time = 1 .. T;
range Product = 1.. P;

tuple demand {
  int Product;
  int Node;
  int Days;
  float Demands;
}

tuple matrix {
  int NodesFrom;
  int NodesTo;
  float Distance;
}

tuple route {
  int NodesFrom;
  int NodesTo;
}

int Storage[Node] = ...;//storage capacity
int TCost = ...;//travel cost
{demand} DemandSet = ...;//demand of supermarket
{matrix} MatrixSet = ...;// distance matrix
{route} RouteSet = {< Nf, Nt > | < Nf, Nt, D > in MatrixSet};
{int} CustomerSupplierSet = {Nf | < Nf, Nt, D > in MatrixSet};// number of nodes
{int} ProductSet = {P | < P, N, T, D > in DemandSet};// number of product types
float Holding = ...;//inventory holding cost
float VCapacity = ...;//vehicle capacity

dvar boolean x[Vehicle][RouteSet][Time];//node I is traversed by vehicle v
dvar float y[ProductSet][Vehicle][RouteSet][Time];//Amount of product pcarried by vehicle v
dvar float r[ProductSet][CustomerSupplierSet][Time];//Amount of on-hand inventory of product p by customer I

dexpr float fixed_cost = sum ( v in Vehicle, < Nf, Nt, D > in MatrixSet,
   t in Time ) x[v][< 0, Nt >][t] * f;
dexpr float transport_cost = sum ( v in Vehicle, < Nf, Nt, D > in MatrixSet,
   t in Time ) x[v][< Nf, Nt >][t] * D * TCost;
dexpr float holding_cost = sum ( p in ProductSet, c in CustomerSupplierSet,
   t in Time ) r[p][c][t] * Holding;

minimize
  fixed_cost + transport_cost + holding_cost;
subject to {
//Constraint 1
  forall ( v in Vehicle, t in Time ) {
    sum ( < i, j > in RouteSet ) x[v][< i, j >][t] <= 1;
  }
//Constraint 2  
  forall ( v in Vehicle, i in CustomerSupplierSet, t in Time ) {
    sum ( j in CustomerSupplierSet ) x[v][< i, j >][t] + sum 
      ( k in CustomerSupplierSet ) x[v][< k, i >][t] == 0;
  }
//Constraint 3  
  forall ( v in Vehicle, < i, j > in RouteSet, t in Time ) {
    sum ( p in ProductSet ) y[p][v][< i, j >][t] <= VCapacity * x[v][< i,
       j >][t];
  }
//Constraint 4  
  forall ( v in Vehicle, t in Time, p in ProductSet, i in CustomerSupplierSet )
     {
    sum ( j in CustomerSupplierSet ) y[p][v][< j, i >][t] + sum 
      ( k in CustomerSupplierSet ) y[p][v][< i, k >][t] >= 0;
  }
//Constraint 5
  forall ( < p, i, t, d > in DemandSet ) {
    r[p][i][t-1] - r[p][i][t] + sum ( v in Vehicle ) ( sum 
      ( j in CustomerSupplierSet ) y[p][v][< j, i >][t] + sum 
      ( k in CustomerSupplierSet ) y[p][v][< i, k >][t] ) == d;
  }
//Constraint 6
  forall ( i in Customer, t in Time ) {
    sum (p in ProductSet) r[p][i][t] <= Storage[i];
  }
//Constraint 7
  forall ( i in CustomerSupplierSet, t in Time, p in ProductSet ) {
    r[p][i][t] >= 0;
  }
//Constraint 8  
  forall ( p in ProductSet, < i, k > in RouteSet, v in Vehicle, t in Time ) {
    y[p][v][< i, k >][t] >= 0;
  }
}

.dat
SheetConnection data ("Data irp.xlsx");
DemandSet from SheetRead(data,"Demand!Demand");
Storage from SheetRead(data,"Data!Capacity");
TCost from SheetRead(data,"Data!Travel_cost");
MatrixSet from SheetRead(data,"Data!Route");
Holding from SheetRead(data,"Data!Holding");
VCapacity from SheetRead(data,"Data!VCapacity");


instead of
//Constraint 5
  forall ( < p, i, t, d > in DemandSet ) {
    r[p][i][t-1] - r[p][i][t] + sum ( v in Vehicle ) ( sum 
      ( j in CustomerSupplierSet ) y[p][v][< j, i >][t] + sum 
      ( k in CustomerSupplierSet ) y[p][v][< i, k >][t] ) == d;
  }

I would rather write
//Constraint 5
  forall ( < p, i, t, d > in DemandSet:(t-1) in Time ) {
    r[p][i][t-1] - r[p][i][t] + sum ( v in Vehicle ) ( sum 
      ( j in CustomerSupplierSet ) y[p][v][< j, i >][t] + sum 
      ( k in CustomerSupplierSet ) y[p][v][< i, k >][t] ) == d;
  }

to make sure that t-1 belongs to Time
